# plotting a dictionary made from a TAB2 file

Tags: python, matplotlib, networkx

I have imported counter from collections, networkx (as nx) and matplotlib (as plt). I have taken the degrees of each node in a graph that I have made. but then I would like to plot the number of degrees vs the degree frequency. My attempt is as follows:

```
        deg=list(G.degree().values())
        count=Counter(deg)
        for data_dict in count:
          x = data_dict.keys()
          y = data_dict.values()
        plt.scatter(x,y)
        plt.legend(d.keys())
        plt.show()
```

The following error is returned:

```
        AttributeError: 'int' object has no attribute 'keys'
```

So are the integers contained in the dictionary given by the counter command uniterable? if so how do I deal with this to plot the graph?

Comment: Can you extend your code sample? It remains unclear, in what line your ``AttributeError`` is raised, and ``d`` (on which ``keys()`` is also evoked) is not defined.

Comment: The values in the keys are uniformly integers. However the error arises at x = data_dict.keys() specifically pertainint to the "keys". otherwise I'm not sure how else to debug the code as everything above that prints

Comment: You should always include the full error message which will tell you what line number the error occurs on.  In this case, I'm pretty sure it's `d.keys()`.  As general debugging advice: it's telling you something is wrong with that line.  So right before that, tell it to `print d`.  You'll find out `d` isn't what you think it is.

Answer (score 0):

You can drop the loop and simply pull the keys and values from the 'count' object.

```
count=Counter(deg)
x = count.keys()
y = count.values()
plt.scatter(x,y)
```